# How Promise works?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am learning Promise in JS and I have few queries related to it.

This is a code snippet I have,

```js
var promise = new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => {
    var data = 'resolve';
    resolve(data);
    console.log('promise executor');
  });

setTimeout(
  () => {
    promise.then(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    promise.then(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }, 2000);
```

The output comes as,

```
promise executor
resolve
resolve
```

From the above output, I understand that body of `executor` has executed immediately during construction of Promise. Now, I have few doubts/queries as follows,

1. During `executor`'s execution, `resolve` was actually undefined. Still, the browser does not throw error and discards the call, how?
2. The `resolve` function is set after a delay of 2 seconds. Still browser calls the function, though the `executor` has already executed and `data` variable has lost the life. How?
3. Second time setting of `resolve` also gives an output. Doesn't it have limitation in number of calls to `.then()` ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by #1. `resolve` was never `undefined`.

Comment: You misunderstand what `resolve` is and what `then` does. `then` doesn't set a `resolve` function. It adds a function to the list of functions to run after the `resolve` function has been called. You don't every create a function to assign to the identifier `resolve` in that code. The Promise constructor does that one time as soon as you construct a `new Promise`, so `resolve` is never `undefined`, nor is it ever either of the functions you passed into `then`.

Comment: 3. You can call as many `.then' as you want but remember changing the result changes also the value to the next then. A good explanation can be found at Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises  under Chaining

Comment: @Ryan. Sorry, I meant by undefined not by its value, actually by its availability.

Comment: If you want to learn ```Promises``` thoroughly, please go through this excellent course on Udacity. It's Free.

https://in.udacity.com/course/javascript-promises--ud898

Comment: @SandipNirmal `resolve` is available immediately, before you ever call `then`. It is never `undefined`.

Comment: `Second time setting of resolve` - no, resolve is called once only in your code - you are confused with the fact that once a promise is resolved (using resolve or reject) any subsequent calls to resolve/reject are silently ignored

Comment: @SandipNirmal Thanks for the info, but the point of interest here is not chaining, but using same promise again.

Comment: Then you should have a look at observables. Here would be a guide for both https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `resolve` there is a natural parameter of the `promise` constructor - it *does* exist. (Feel free to add in `console.log(typeof resolve);`)
2. At this point, the promise has run, and is now *a resolved promise with the value of 'resolve'.* The `data` variable doesn't really exist at that point, but the promise still has been resolved with that `'resolve'` value. So, further `.then`s added to the promise will immediately run with that value.
3. No, no limitation - that's one of the great things about promises, you can pass them around without being limited to only one `.then`. Check out the docs if you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: For 3 feel free to add the official documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: @Doomenik Since when is a wiki that anyone can edit "official documentation"?

Comment: Since for js, every browser has its own engine (some only a little modified) and there only exists a standard, I call the engine creator official. Means Mozilla, Google, IE, Apple, Oracle. And unofficial something like W3. But your right some other word would have fitted better I just have no idea which :)

Answer (score 1):

**1**.A promise may be in one of 3 possible states: **fulfilled, rejected, or pending**. Promise users can attach callbacks to handle the fulfilled value or the reason for rejection.

The promise constructor takes one argument, a callback with two parameters, resolve and reject. Do something within the callback, perhaps async, then call resolve if everything worked, otherwise call reject.

A promise is an object which can be returned synchronously from an asynchronous function. It will be in one of 3 possible states:

**Fulfilled**: onFulfilled() will be called (e.g., resolve() was called)

**Rejected**: onRejected() will be called (e.g., reject() was called)

**Pending**: not yet fulfilled or rejected

A promise is settled if it’s not pending (it has been resolved or rejected). Sometimes people use resolved and settled to mean the same thing: not pending.
Once settled, a promise can not be resettled. Calling resolve() or reject() again will have no effect. The immutability of a settled promise is an important feature.

**2** .The fact promises do not resolve immediately sometimes and defer sometimes means that the API is consistent. Otherwise, you get undefined behavior in the order of execution.

**3**.Once the promise gets resolved, `.then` function gets called immediately so if for one promise you write `n` number of `.then` functions then all will get executed at same time with same data sent in resolve.